# Calling Fortran subroutines with array arguments from Julia

Tags: arrays, fortran, julia, fortran90, gfortran

I can call compile this fortran code 'test.f90'

```
subroutine test(g,o)
double precision, intent(in):: g
double precision, intent(out):: o
o=g*g
end subroutine
```

with

```
gfortran -shared -fPIC test.f90 -o test.so
```

and create this wraper function test.jl for Julia:

```
function test(s)
  res=Float64[1]
  ccall((:test_, "./test.so"), Ptr{Float64}, (Ptr{Float64}, Ptr{Float64}), &s,res);
  return res[1]
end
```

and run these command with the sought for output:

```
julia> include("./test.jl")    
julia> test(3.4)
11.559999999999999
```

But I want to return an array instead of a scalar. I think I have tried everyting, including using the iso_c_binding, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373693/calling-a-fortran-function-from-julia-returning-an-array-unknown-function-seg) answer. But everything I try throws errors at me looking like this:

```
ERROR: MethodError: `convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{Ptr{Array{Int32,2}}}, ::Array{Int32,2})
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor Ptr{Array{Int32,2}}(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
Closest candidates are:
  call{T}(::Type{T}, ::Any)
  convert{T}(::Type{Ptr{T}}, ::UInt64)
  convert{T}(::Type{Ptr{T}}, ::Int64)
  ...
 [inlined code] from ./deprecated.jl:417
 in unsafe_convert at ./no file:429496729
```

As an example, I'd like to call the following code from julia:

```
subroutine arr(array) ! or  arr(n,array)
implicit none
integer*8, intent(inout) :: array(:,:)
!integer*8, intent(in) :: n
!integer*8, intent(out) :: array(n,n)
integer :: i, j

do i=1,size(array,2) !n
    do j=1,size(array,1) !n
        array(i,j)= j+i
    enddo
enddo
end subroutine
```

Using the commented out variant is also an alternative as only changing the argument doesn't seem to be useful when calling from julia.

So how do I call fortran subroutines with arrays from Julia?

Comment: You say you tried `iso_c_binding`, do you mean by that actually `bind(C)` or did you just use the `iso_c_binding` module? In which way exactly? Which exact code corresponds to the error message in the question?

Comment: `integer*8` is not standard conforming and was never part of any ISO FORTRAN/Fortran standard.  You can employ the named constant `INT64` from the intrinsic module `ISO_Fortran_env` or  `C_INT64_T` from `ISO_C_binding`, or `selected_int_kind` to use large integers in a safe portable manner.

Comment: Why does your ccall  to _test describe a function returning a pointer when the Fortran procedure is a subroutine?

Comment: And you *definitely* do not want assumed shape array `(:,:)` when doing anything connected with interoperability between languages. Always use simple `(n,n)`. At least until you learn how to use the internals of array descriptors.

Comment: On ifort one cannot have a BIND C function that returns an array.

Comment: @VladimirF When i tried the iso_c_binding, I used both `bind(C,name="test")` and `use`d the module, as in the link. I didn't know i defined the function to return a pointer, what in the function defines that? In the example in the end, I show what I would like to accomplish. The things i tried were as close as possible to what worked with a scalar, but there are like 50 combinations of failing approaches that woulden't be very valuable to post. @Holmz, I'm using gfortran.

Comment: The second parameter of ccall is the return type, se the answer below, a subroutine should have Void.

Comment: I guess you mean the Ptr{}, I didn't realize until now that was short for pointer.

Comment: @VladimirF Just a comment on your statement about interoperability and assumed shape arrays: When using F2PY to build python-wrapped libraries from fortran code, it is actually required to use assumed shape `arrays(:,:)` in order to pass an array from python to the called subroutine.

Comment: F2py is a special case, I was speaking about interfacing other languages from Fortran directly. F2py uses those internals I was speaking about and hides them from you. It is possible to do that by hand but it is very difficult.  But no, you are not right, you can use explicit shape and assumed size arrays with F2PY. Alas, most of them are that way, just open the libraries that come with NumPY, most of them are FORTRAN 77, and there are no assumed shape arrays in FORTRAN 77.

Comment: Look here and around https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/master/scipy/fftpack You will be lucky to find any assumed shape array at all...

Comment: The rule I wrote is really valid. Unless you have something, which explicitly says it is capable to interface Fortran assumed shape arrays, don't use them for any interoperability. They are tricky. See `ISO_Fortran_binding.h` in ftp://ftp.nag.co.uk/sc22wg5/n1901-n1950/n1942.pdf

Comment: @VladimirF You are right as usual! When I wrapped with explicit shape arrays `subroutine test(m,n,array)` i called it with `wrap.test(m,n,array)`, which is wrong. In python `>>> print wrap.test.__doc__` tells you that the call is`wrap.test(array)`, same as with assumed shape array calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `ccall`, Julia arrays should be passed as pointers of the element type, along with an extra argument describing the size.

Your example `test.f90` should be:

```
subroutine arr(n,array)
implicit none
integer*8, intent(in) :: n
integer*8, intent(out) :: array(n,n)
integer :: i, j

do i=1,size(array,2) !n
    do j=1,size(array,1) !n
        array(i,j)= j+i
    enddo
enddo
end subroutine
```

Compiled as before with

```
gfortran -shared -fPIC test.f90 -o test.so
```

Then in Julia:

```
n = 10
X = zeros(Int64,n,n) # 8-byte integers
ccall((:arr_, "./test.so"), Void, (Ptr{Int64}, Ptr{Int64}), &n, X)
```

Comment: This workes perfectly, thank you! I think that the most consistent mistake i made, that kept me from running pretty much this exact code, was that I was mostly trying with `Ptr{Array{Int64,2}}` as the output variable specifier and/or return type in the `ccall`.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion:
'&n' will cause invalid syntax error for newer versions.
And, using Ref is safer than Ptr.

You may try:

```
ccall((:arr_, "./test.so"), Cvoid, (Ref{Int64}, Ref{Int64}), Ref(n), X)
```

Comment: In which way is it safer? Is it compatible then?

Comment: It seems the best (only?) way for Julia 1.1.0 to call fortran function.